# The derivative of $x!$

Tags: derivatives

I was trying to calculate the derivative of $x!$ but i ran into a large amount of numbers. Is it even possible to calculate it? Because in an app called *GRAPHER* when i type in $(x!)'$ it returnes the graph of this function.
Here it is:

[image: x factorial]

Comment: To define $x!$ you need the Gamma function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: That was helpful thanks

Answer (score 6):

The function $ f(x) = x! $ is well defined only for $ x \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \} $. The derivatives of such a function do not exist; it'n not even a continuous function! An extention of $f$ for $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ is the Gamma Function; and it's got derivatives.

Comment: Just to nitpick -- as $\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ is a discrete space, the factorial function is continuous. The problem is that it's not defined on $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Gamma function, the most well-known generalization of factorial, is given by the formula below:

$\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$      $(x>0)$

It is straightforward from the definition that $\Gamma(1)=1$ and $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$, so for a positive integer $n$, $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ holds.

Then we get $\Gamma'(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\ln tdt$.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function gives the derivative of the Gamma function:

$\Gamma'(m+1) = m! \left( - \gamma + \sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k} \right)\,.$

Answer (score 2):

Note that what you are looking to derive is $z!$. This means that you have to extend the factorial function over the reals. So basically we want a function $f(x)$ such that $$f(x+1)=(x+1)f(x)$$ Fortunately, Wikipedia contatins some information on [extending the factorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Extension_of_factorial_to_non-integer_values_of_argument). One such extension is called the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), which is defined as  $$z!=\Gamma (z+1)=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{z}e^{-x} \mathrm{d}x$$
We can check that the Gamma function satisfies $$\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$$$$\Gamma(1)=1$$
As proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538817/proof-that-the-gamma-function-is-an-extension-of-the-factorial-function). However, you are curious about it's derivative. We also need to know what the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) is to learn about that. Note that the digamma function is defined as $$\psi (x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln\left(\Gamma(x)\right)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$$
So the derivative of $\Gamma (x)$ is $\Gamma (x) \psi(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $x\mapsto x! = x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ only makes sense when $x$ is a nonnegative integer ($0,1,2,3,\ldots$). It is not defined for all real numbers. That's a problem when you try to find its derivative --- remember, from the definition of a derivative, it's 
$$ f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} $$
So to differentiate the factorial function we'd have to be able to figure out what $(x+h)!$ is for very small $h$. For example, to find the derivative of the factorial function at $6$ we'd have to be able to find $6.003!$

So the question is, *what is a good way to **extend** the factorial function*? In other words, is there a *new* function we can come up with, that is defined on all the real numbers and is *also* equal to the factorial function on the nonnegative integers?

The answer is: Yes. As other answers point out, the natural extension is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) 
$$ \Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\ dt $$
The reason it's a natural extension of the factorial function involves integration by parts, and is a good exercise in a second calculus class. When people talk about the derivative of the factorial function, they're talking about the derivative of the Gamma function.

Comment: Simple and clear. I appreciate your answer @Neal